# Office.context.mailbox.item.notificationMessages disappear on web app, on reload or messages switching

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

### How to persist notifications on outlook web application

I'm using the following function.
Message persists on the Outlook Desktop application, but on the Outlook web application disappears when switching between email messages or reloading the page.

**plus icon also not appear on web, which is the correct icon resolution for the web because 80x80 appears on Desktop app**

```
const addNotificationMessage=(text)=>{
    const message = {
        type: Office.MailboxEnums.ItemNotificationMessageType.InformationalMessage,
        message: text,
        persistent: true,
        icon: "Icon80",
      };
      Office.context.mailbox.item.notificationMessages.replaceAsync("action", message);
    }
```

Comment: Does this issue happens only when you create a new mail and add notification message to that?

Comment: No, I never test that.when i read existing emails and add a notification, it disappears.

Comment: Thanks for reporting this issue regarding persistent notification messages. It has been put on our backlog. We, unfortunately, have no timelines to share at this point.
Internal tracking id: Office: 3402248

Comment: Could you please try emptying the Cache and performing a hard refresh, to see if this resolves the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug. I've reproduced this issue in Outlook for the web and Outlook for desktop on Windows. So, I've filed it as an issue. You may track it at https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/3155 .

Be aware, the documentation states that in modern Outlook on the web, you can add an `InsightMessage` notification only in `Compose mode`.

At present, the custom icon is displayed in Outlook on Windows only and not on other clients (e.g., Mac, web browser).